# A form be transparent and click thru - but still receive dragdrop events

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a form which I overlay on another form and use transparency key to set it to transparent and click thru-able, track the other forms position and set it to parent.  All works fine and happily.

What I would really like is for this transparent and click thru-able form to receive drag and drop events, but I suspect that using TransparencyKey means that all mouse events are click thru-able including drag and drop?

So far i haven't been able to google myself out of it, so wondered if anyone here would know better ?

Many thanks,
Ian.

Comment: This isn't going to work of course.  If you need "drop anywhere" support then recurse through the controls of the bottom form and set their AllowDrop and D+D event handlers.

Answer (score -1):

[Code Project Article on Transparent Click-through Forms (VB.NET)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12877/Transparent-Click-Through-Forms)

Converted to C# from the article.

#### Win32 APIs:

- [`GetWindowLong`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633584(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [`SetWindowLong`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633591(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [`SetLayeredWindowAttributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633540(v=vs.85).aspx)

#### DLL Imports

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowLongA", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int nIndex);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLongA", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetLayeredWindowAttributes(IntPtr hwnd, uint crKey, byte bAlpha, uint dwFlags);
```

#### Example

```
private const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
private const int WS_EX_LAYERED = 0x80000;
private const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x20;
private const int LWA_ALPHA = 2;
private const int LWA_COLOR_KEY = 1;

var style = GetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE)

SetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, 
                  style | WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT)

var percent = 0.7
var alpha = 255 * percent
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(this.Handle, 0, alpha, LWA_ALPHA)
```